# Proof of property with Riemann integral

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, riemann-integration

> Suppose we have a function $f:[-1,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
> $$
> f(x)= \begin{cases}
> -1, & -1\leq x\leq 0 \\
> 1,  & 0<x\leq 1
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Using the Riemann definition of the integral, prove that $\int_{-1}^xf=|x|-1$ for any $x\in[-1,1]$.

**My attempt:** By Riemann's definition of the integral we can say
$$
\int_{-1}^x f
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(c_k) \Delta x_k
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}-1\Delta x_k +\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x\Delta x_k
 = -1 + |x|.
$$

Comment: Which definition of Riemann integral are you using in which the Riemann integral of a function is the sum of a series?

Comment: Hi, the definition I have been taught is that $\int_a^bf=\lim{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf(c_k)\Delta x_k$, where $\Delta x_k$ is the norm

Answer (score 1):

so for any $-1\le x\le0$ we have:
$$\int_{-1}^xf\,dx=(-1)\times (x+1)$$
now for any $0\le x\le 1$ we have:
$$\int_{-1}^xf dx=\int_{-1}^0(-1)dx+\int_0^x\,d\mathbb{x}=-1+x=x-1$$
so if we have $F'=f$ then we know that:
$$F=\begin{cases}-x-1 & -1\le x<0\\
                 -1   & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x=0\\
                 x-1  & \,\,\,0< x\le 1\end{cases}$$